# MVC 5 hosting on !and1

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-5, hosting

I want to host MVC 5 application on 1and1, i searched in their site and other but did not find any help.

I just want to know is there any support for MVC 5 on 1and1.

If yes can you please help me by providing some links or code.

Thank you in Advance.

Comment: Use a hosting service that does have a good site to guide you, or in the future you would clearly be troubled again. BTW, your current question is off-topic.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, i solved it by removing all the files in the production except the required published files, then my problem is fixed.

Comment: Thank you so much @DouglasThomas for your suggestion... :)